# Asp Net Core 3.0 GenerateAssemblyInfo = False is breaking my UserSecrets

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0

For some very odd reason when I attempt to add a GenerateAssemblyInfo flag to my local branch all of my user secrets fail to be replaced in my appsettings.json.

Does anyone happen to have any idea why this may be happening?

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  <UserSecretsId>aspnet-SomeStuff</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up having to add the following line to my AssemblyInfo.cs and it worked like expected.

```
[assembly: UserSecretsId("aspnet-SomeStuff")]
```

Comment: I can confirm that the same problem still exists in ASP.NET Core 5. Just to clarify: You need to add the same GUID to `[assembly: UserSecretsId("GUID")]` that is stored in the .csproj file under `UserSecretsId`.

Comment: I have opened a corresponding bug report [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/37901).